# Temporarily changing a property

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

Is it possible to achieve through data templates a behavior so, that I can change the foreground color of a cell for just 'x' seconds and then return it to its original color.

E.g. I define a data template like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ChangeTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource percentConverter}, Path=ChangePercent}" 
                                     Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource decimalToColorConverter}, Path=ChangePercent}" />
        </DataTemplate>
```

Can you please guide me how can I achieve the behavior so, that after 'x' amount of time I change it back to its original foreground color.

Thanks,
SC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using an [animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) which does not use the [hold-end-behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.fillbehavior.aspx), thus the property will return to the initial value after it is finished.